# Pytest failed when testing API with correct URL and data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, pytest-django

When I am creating a `Clinic` via `Swagger` or `Postman` it works fine and field with the same data when test it !

**model**

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   price = models.FloatField()
   doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doctor_clinic')
   date = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicDate, related_name='clinic_date')
```

**serializer**

```
class ClinicDateSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
          model = ClinicDate
          fields = ['day','start_time', 'end_time']


class ClinicSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   doctor = serializers.StringRelatedField(required=False)
   date = ClinicDateSerializers(many=True, required=True)
   class Meta:
          model = Clinic 
          fields = ['name', 'price', 'doctor', 'date']

   def create(self, validated_data):
          dates_data = None
          if 'date' in validated_data:
              dates_data = validated_data.pop('date')
          user =  self.context['request'].user
          clinic = Clinic.objects.create(doctor=user, **validated_data)
          if dates_data != None:
             for date_data in dates_data:
                 dt = ClinicDate.objects.create(**date_data)
                 clinic.date.add(dt)
                 clinic.save()
          return clinic
```

**URL**

```
path('add/', views.ClinicCreateView.as_view(), name='clinic-create'),
```

**pytest**

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestClinic:

   @pytest.fixture
   def setup(self):
          User.objects.create_doctor(email="doctor1@doctoronline.com", password="12345")
          data = {
                 'email':'doctor1@doctoronline.com',
                 'password':'12345', 
          }
          response = client.post(reverse('token_obtain_pair_doctor'), data=data)
          self.access_token = response.json()['access']       
          client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer ' + self.access_token)

   def test_valid_create_clinic(self, setup):
          data = {
                 "name": "Clinic 1",
                 "price": 1000,
                 "date": [
                        {
                        "day": "SATURDAY",
                        "start_time": "2021-08-24T21:21:17.960Z",
                        "end_time": "2021-08-24T21:21:17.960Z"
                        }
                    ]
                 }
          response = client.post(reverse('clinic-create'), data=data)
          assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

**Swagger Snapshot**

[image]
[image]

**Hint** there is no problem with `setup` or `data`

Comment: What error/status code/ exceptions do you get?

Comment: @bdbd error 400 bad request

Comment: A bit hard to figure out just by the status code. Can you run with debug set to true or put breakpoints in the view?

Comment: I figured out that happened  because I set `required=True` in `date` inside serializer, if I set `required=False` It will work fine. I have no idea why that happened but It should be  `required=True` and the `date` formate is correct!!

Comment: Can you show us `response.data`?

Comment: In testing, I can just access specific field in `response.data` anyway the data is saved when I set `required=False` in `date` otherwise it did not saved

Comment: @bdbd I answered the question if you are curious to know what was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: The problem was that I'm dealing with nested serializer and by default multipart format does not support nested data so, I just want to set `formate = 'json'

```
response = client.post(reverse('clinic-create'), data=data, format='json')
```